# stream large files in node.js lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, fs

I am new to javascript have written some nodejs code to calculate checksum of files in `S3` by streaming using the crypto module. It does fine when the items are small sizes `(1-5GB)`, larger files will timeout because not all the stream data has been consumed by the time lambda timeout is up and end event have not been reached. I am wondering if there are ways to tune this code such that it will handles the big files in about `30gb` range? I noticed that in my lambda the cpu memory is barely being fully utilized, each time it only uses about `10% 148mb/1530mb` allocated, can I do anything there? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
let s3params = {
    Bucket: 'nlm-qa-int-draps-bucket',
    //Key: filename.toString(),
    Key: '7801339A.mkv',
};
let hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
let stream = s3.getObject(s3params).createReadStream();
stream.on('data', (data) => {
    hash.update(data);
});
stream.on('end', () => {
            var digest = hash.digest('hex');
            console.log("this is md5 value from digest: " + digest);
            callback(null, digest);
            digest = digest.toString().replace(/[^A-Za-z 0-9 \.,\?""!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+;:<>\/\\\|\}\{\[\]`~]*/g, '');
```

Comment: What throughput are you getting there? How long does it take to get the digest a 1gb file?

Comment: it takes one minutes or so for 1gb digest, 16gb seems to be the limit with max time to run at 4.9min. 17gb will fail everytime

Comment: If you download the file to disk, does it also take this much time?